Can the US Defence Secretary revoke any plea deal they want?
I read that US Defence Secretary Lloyd Austin has revoked a pre-trial agreement reached with men accused of plotting the 11 September 2001 terrorist attacks.. Can the US Defence Secretary revoke any plea deal they want?

Certainly not in the context of normal criminal trials conducted by the judicial branch.  This trial is not such a trial, but the question does not make it clear that you are aware of that.

@phoog thanks, I'm not aware of that

No.  The defense secretary has this authority in this trial because it is a military tribunal that is conducted under his command.  He therefore has the authority to direct the presiding officer to make certain decisions and, as in this case, to assume certain aspects of the presiding officer's authority.
The presiding officer is analogous to a judge in a normal court of law, but the federal judiciary is not constituted like a military tribunal; there is no single officer who has authority over a federal judge; instead, there is a hierarchy of courts.  In any event, no officer of the executive branch has any such authority over any judge or court of the judicial branch.
An overview of the military tribunal is available in the Wikipedia article Guantanamo military commission.

The AG can override a US attorney though

@littleadv yes, a plea deal needs the agreement of both the prosecutor and the defendant.  But it also requires approval by the court -- by the judge -- and in this case the person Austin is overruling is the judge, not the prosecutor.

Are you sure about that? I think it's actually the prosecutor.

@littleadv the article linked in the question says that the person whom Austin has overruled is "Brig Gen Susan Escallier" and a quick search on her name shows that she was appointed as the "convening authority" of the tribunal, which I understand to be analogous to a judge (the NY Times describes the role as having authority to decide whether prosecutors can seek the death penalty).  But no, I'm not sure.  I'll look for some more information.  Wikipedia seems to be down at the moment; at least I can't reach it.

https://www.nytimes.com/2024/08/02/us/politics/911-plotters-plea-deal.html identifies Gen. Escallier as an "overseer", but the judge is Col. Matthew McCall.  So maybe Escallier's role needs more explanation, but she isn't the judge.

"Convening Authority: A person in the military who has the power to call for a court-martial to be held. This person is usually a commanding officer." from here

@littleadv The convening authority basically a super-judge, and the trial is conducted under their command prerogative. They determine that the charges should be referred to trial and select a judge and a panel (jury) which holds a trial and returns a recommended verdict. The convening authority examines the verdict and conduct of the trial and clemency requests from the accused. They can accept the sentence, lower certain guilty findings to lesser offenses, lower sentences, set aside a conviction due to legal error, order a rehearing (mistrial) of the verdict or sentence.
